# Remove duplicates from Array of Array (nested array of objects)

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an Array which holds another Array of objects. I would like to remove the duplicates in this array of array.

```
var arr1 = [{
     child: [{name: "google", check: false}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "excite", check: false}, {name: "facebook", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "something1", check: false}, {name: "something2", check: false}]
    }
]

var arr2 = [{
     child: [{name: "google", check: true}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "excite", check: false}, {name: "facebook", check: false}]
    } 
]

var arr3 = [{
     child: [{name: "google", check: true}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "excite", check: false}, {name: "facebook", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "something1", check: false}, {name: "something2", check: false}]
    }
]
```

I would like to remove `{name: "google", check: false}` from the second child array as there is already one with same name and `check: true` in `arr1`.

Below is something what i have tried.

```
function mergeAndRemoveDuplicates(arr1, arr2) {

    return arr1.map(function(child) {
        return child.some(function(children) {
            return arr2.map(function(child2) {
                return child2.some(function(children2) {
                    return children.name === children2.name &&
                        children.check === true;
                });
            })
        })
    })
}

console.log(mergeAndRemoveDuplicates(arr1, arr2));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g7rvbpf3/

Comment: please add the result as well. what do you mean with merge?

Comment: @FlashThunder We don't always get to choose our data. Even if we did, there's likely a nicer way to ask the same question.

Comment: Remove {name: "google", check: false} from the arr2 as its already there in arr1 and merge arr1 and arr2.

Comment: @NinaScholz: I have updated the final output... thanks

Comment: For what I'm looking after the update, it appears that you want to update the data of `arr1` with the new upcoming data from `arr2`. Is that what you really want?

Comment: @Shidersz: Yes... thats what i am looking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding that you want to update the `check` properties of the elements in `arr1` based on the new upcoming data from `arr2`, one possible approach can be to first create a hash table between the new upcoming `name` and `check` values. For this part we use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce). The second part of the approach consiste of [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the elements of the `arr1` to hold the new updates.

```js
var arr1 = [
    {
     child: [{name: "google", check: false}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "excite", check: false}, {name: "facebook", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "something1", check: false}, {name: "something2", check: false}]
    }
];

var arr2 = [
    {
     child: [{name: "google", check: true}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "excite", check: false}, {name: "facebook", check: false}]
    } 
];

let upHashTable = arr2.reduce((acc, {child}) =>
{
    child.forEach(({name, check}) => acc[name] = check);
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log("HashTable with updates: ", upHashTable);

let updated = arr1.map(({child}) =>
{
    return {child: child.map(o =>
    {
        o.check = upHashTable.hasOwnProperty(o.name) ? upHashTable[o.name] : o.check;
        return o;
    })};
});

console.log("Updated arr1 is: ", updated);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Note this will only update values on `arr1` and will not insert any new elements on it.

Comment: Thanks, but the output is array containing another array of objects... instead array of objects ... like below... var arr3 = [{
     child: [{name: "google", check: true}, {name: "yahoo", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "excite", check: false}, {name: "facebook", check: false}]
    },
    {
     child: [{name: "something1", check: false}, {name: "something2", check: false}]
    }
]

Comment: @Thalapathy, sorry, I missed that part, I just updated to contemplate it.

Answer (score 3):

You could create a set of checked names and recursively filter the arrays:

```
const dupes = new Set;

for(const el of arr1.concat(arr2))
  el.child = el.child.filter(el => {
     const dupe = dupes.has(el.name);
     if(el.check) dupes.add(el.name);
     return !dupe;
  });
```

This will also filter duplicates in `arr1`, if that isn't wanted you could use `arr1` to build up the set, and filter `arr2`:

```
 const dupes = new Set;

 for(const child of arr1.flatMap(it => it.child))
   if(child.checked) dupes.add(child.name);

for(const el of arr2)
 el.child = el.child.filter(it => !dupes.has(it.name));
```

To get one array at the end (I guess thats what you mean with "merge") you could just `.concat` one to the other.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t1zkLq53/1/ seems flatMap is not available.... should i include any package like rxjs?

Comment: @thalapathy It is ESnext, some browsers might not yet support it, however its just syntactic sugar for a nested loop in this case `for(const el of arr1) for(const child of el.child)` would work too here.